# how to hide specific standard output of shell command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I am doing ssh of a "if statement" to a remote server.

## Example:

========== Start of Script========

```
#!/bin/sh
```

CMD='if [ ! -d "/user/directory" ]; then echo -e "user directory missing"; else echo -e "present"; fi;

ssh remoteserver "$CMD"

==========End of script==========

## Query:

While running this script ,I get welcome message from remote server and then the message given by my if condition. I do not wish to receive the welcome message from remote server. What can be done to supress that ?

## example:

:/root> ./script.sh
Warning Notice
This is a protected network,and if you are not authorized.....

Comment: I have already tried > /dev/null 2>&1 but its also supressing my message from if statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try:

```
    ssh -o LogLevel=Error <rest of cmd>
```

or

```
    ssh remoteserver 'remotecommand args ... 2>&1' 2>/dev/null
```

which will only removes the welcome message.

You can check other solutions in here
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/how-do-you-turn-off-login-banner-for-non-interactive-ssh-470516/

Comment: I am glad that helps. Please mark this as the answer so others would know.